# F# vs Scala - why do I need to tell F# the type of things?

Tags: scala, f#, functional-programming, type-inference

I am starting off my adventures in F# (and Scala). One of the main benefits that the FunProg folks like to talk about is type inference. In Scala I can write something like this:

```
  val x = List(1,2,3)
  x map ((x) => x+1)
```

and the compiler knows that x is a list, and therefor knows to use the map variant of the map function. Further more, I can use the second like on any object that has a map operator, not matter what it is (list, array, Seq, ...)

On the other hand, from all the samples I have seen about F#, you have to do something like:

```
let x = [1;2;3];;
x |> List.map(fun f -> f+1);;
```

So I need to know and define what the type of `x` is and explicitly use `List.map`.That makes little sense to me, and negates the whole "don't worry about the type" argument.

Am I missing something about F#? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `map` is a method in scala while `List.map` is a function in the `List` module in F#. You still need to know the type of `x` in both cases though to know that there's a `map` operation available.

Comment: Thanks @Lee. I get that map is a method on List, but as I am applying the method on a known object (x, which is of type List, why do I need to specify it directly. It makes the whole type-inference idea kind of moot.

Comment: For giggles, I tried `open`ing List in FSI, you know, to see if it worked. Here's the error message's explanation you get by doing that:
> stdin(5,6): error FS0892: This declaration opens the module 'Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List', which is marked as 'RequireQualifiedAccess'. Adjust your code to use qualified references to the elements of the module instead, e.g. 'List.map' instead of 'map'. This change will ensure that your code is robust as new constructs are added to libraries.

Comment: I suppose the error message is consistent with F# not doing function overload resolution on module-level functions.

Comment: I don't have much experience with Scala, but from what I saw actually type inference is much weaker in Scala than F# (so I find this question strange).

Answer (score 6):

It's not a type inference limitation. The problem is that F# core lib doesn't provide generic functions with an overload mechanism. In fact there are some, mainly for generic numbers and other stuff, but just a few.

If you want to write F# code in that style you can have a look at [F#+](https://github.com/gmpl/FSharpPlus). With that library it's perfectly valid to write:

```
let x = [1;2;3];;
x |> map (fun f -> f+1);;

// val it : int list = [2; 3; 4]
```

And it will infer the type for you.

```
let y = Some 2
x |> map (fun f -> f+1);;

// val it : int option = Some 3
```

And it will also work on any type that has a `Map` static method.

So, as you can see F# type inference it's also smart enough. It's just because functions are organized in modules.

Apart from that [there is a proposal](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/506) to allow you to write stuff like:

```
x |> _.map;;
```

or

```
x |> (.map);;
```

But that would only work with instance members, so for `List.map` it wouldn't work as it is right now.

Answer (score 1):

Although it doesn't get much love from hard core FPers, there is actually a fluent library in F#, you can nuget it and than do something like this:

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#r @"..\packages\FSharp.Core.Fluent-4.0.1.0.0.5\lib\portable-net45+netcore45+wpa81+wp8+MonoAndroid1+MonoTouch1\FSharp.Core.Fluent-4.0.dll"
#endif

let x = [1;2;3]
x.map <| (+) 1 // ;-)
//val it : int list = [2; 3; 4]
```

And of course Linq extension methods also work:

```
open System.Linq
x.Select (fun x -> x + 1)
//val it : System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int> = seq [2; 3; 4]
```